# Get string value of column using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to fetch the string value of an IP address stored in my users table with SQLALchemy and Python3.10. When I run the below query however, I am getting an object back rather than just the string.

How can I get just the string value?

```
def get_user_ip(user_id):
    try:
        return User.query.with_entities(User.ip_address).filter_by(id=user_id)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        return None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.query.with_entities(User.ip_address).filter_by(id=user_id)` produces a [Query](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query) instance, but does not *execute* it. To get a result, execute the query by calling one of these methods:

- [first](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.first)(): return the first result in the resultset
- [one](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.one)(): return one result, raise error if number of results is not one
- [one_or_none](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.one_or_none)(): return one or none (error if more than one result)
- [all](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.all)(): return a list of all results

For example:

```py
...
    return User.query.with_entities(User.ip_address).filter_by(id=user_id).first()
```

You can also iterate over the query instead of calling a method, but that does not suit your use case.